# Missing ; before identifier cout

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am completing my school project. I wrote everything but there seems to be a error:

> missing ";" before cout at line 15 before " your number is bigger
>   than..."

I can not understand this error or fix it. Please help. The code for the whole program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int intSecretNum = 47;
    int intGuess;
    cout<< "Guess the secret number (between 0 and 100 inclusively): ";
    cin>> intGuess;
    while(intSecretNum != 47, intGuess<= 5)
    {
            if( intGuess < intSecretNum)
                cout << "Your Number is smaller than the secret number";
            else (intGuess > intSecretNum)
                cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
            intGuess++;
            if(intGuess>5)
                cout << "Sorry, you have used up all your quota (5 times)! The secret number is "<<intSecretNum;
                cout << "program terminated." <<endl;
    }
    cout<< "You have used "<<intGuess <<"to guess te secret number which is " <<intSecretNum<<".";
    cout<<"program terminated."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty new to this C++ please help

Comment: `else (intGuess > intSecretNum)` --> `else` does not take a condition `else if` does

Comment: There are other things as well, what is the point of `intSecretNum != 47` in the while loop? What do you do if your `intguess == intSecretNum` ?

Comment: What do you want to happen when guess matches secret number?

Comment: Also: (1) You need to use `cin` inside the loop to ask for a new guess. (2) You seem to use `intGuess` for both the number of guesses so far *and* the number guessed. You need two variables instead of one. (3) Unless your teacher asked you to (bad idea) you may want to avoid prefixing the variable name with its type. This tends to make variable names more verbose and cryptic.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here

```
else (intGuess > intSecretNum)
            cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
```

This assumes that `(intGuess > intSecretNum)` is a statement which would be executed under the `else` condition, which is why you get an error warning you of a missing semicolon.

Instead you should have

```
else if(intGuess > intSecretNum)
            cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this line:

```
else (intGuess > intSecretNum)
```

to

```
else if( intGuess > intSecretNum)
```

The problem is that you cannot give a special condition with just the keyword `else`. Else is used to describe the "in any other case do ...". So in your case since it's a simple test you can simply try to get rid of the condition after else and go from:

else (intGuess > intSecretNum)
to:

```
else
```

For the sake of readability I would also advice to always surround your instructions with `{}` 
This would therefore give you:

```
while(intSecretNum != 47, intGuess<= 5)
    {
            if( intGuess < intSecretNum){
                cout << "Your Number is smaller than the secret number";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
            }
            intGuess++;
            if(intGuess>5)
                cout << "Sorry, you have used up all your quota (5 times)! The secret number is "<<intSecretNum;
                cout << "program terminated." <<endl;
    }
```

NB: There are also some things that do not make sense in your while loop. But that may be the topic for an other question

Answer (score 0):

What you probably mean is:

```
while(intSecretNum != 47, intGuess<= 5)
{
    if( intGuess < intSecretNum)
        cout << "Your Number is smaller than the secret number";
    else if(intGuess > intSecretNum)
        cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
    intGuess++;
    if(intGuess>5) {
        cout << "Sorry, you have used up all your quota (5 times)! The secret number is "<<intSecretNum;
        cout << "program terminated." <<endl;
    }
 }
```

Note the `if` after `else`. `else` does not have a condition like `if`. Also note the brackets around the last `if`-block. Without brackets only one statement makes the whole `if`-block. If you need more, you'll have to enclose the block in brackets.